# Clojure inferior-lisp window in Emacs being displayed over code when doing C-c C-l

Tags: emacs, clojure

I set up my Emacs for Clojure using the instructions [at Clojure's web site](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/clojure/Getting_Started_with_Emacs). I used the first option in setting up the `inferior-lisp-program` variable, basically "java clojure.main".

With this setup, C-c C-z works in getting me to the Clojure REPL. However, when I'm editing a file and I type C-c C-l to load the file into the REPL, Emacs always switches buffer from the code window to the REPL window. This is very irritating. This happens even when I have two windows veritically split, with code on the left and the REPL on the right. I end up with two mirrored REPL windows.

I remember Clojure Box, which is Emacs + Clojure on Windows, does this right, so I know it's a setup issue.

How do I get Emacs to just switch to the window on the right?

Answer (score 1):

I use `C-c C-k` to compile the current buffer. Then the result of that compilation will be available to you in whatever buffer the REPL is running in. Emacs will not switch any buffers around: you're simply compiling the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

In clojure-mode v 1.7.1, which I think is the most recent, `C-c C-l` is bound to `clojure-load-file'`, which has a hard-coded `(switch-to-lisp t)` at the end of it.  In other words, there is no way to prevent it from switching to lisp without redefining `switch-to-lisp` to check a variable to see whether it should actually invoke.

That said, `clojure-load-file` seems a bit heavy-handed in most cases.  My usual workflow involves setting the region to the whole buffer and invoking `lisp-eval-region` with `C-c C-r`.  This function accepts an option `and-go` parameter that indicates whether or not it should switch to the inferior-lisp process buffer or not after invocation.

As I continue working, I usually redefine a functions and evaluate them as I go with `lisp-eval-last-sexp` which I invoke with `C-c C-e`, which also accepts the optional `and-go` flag.

Comment: Sounds like this needs to be fixed in clojure-mode.el; that's a terrible default behaviour. (I have never used clojure-load-file.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SLIME with version 20100404, and this doesn't happen to me, not with `C-c C-l` nor with `C-c C-k`. Maybe you're using a different slime.el version? Use `M-x find-library <RET> slime <RET>` and look for its version in the top comments, to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

In inf-lisp.el you can see that it adds "* inferior-lisp *" to the list of same-buffer windows:

```
(add-hook 'same-window-buffer-names "*inferior-lisp*")
```

To remove it from this list, you can put in your .emacs:

```
(setq same-window-buffer-names (delete "*inferior-lisp*" same-window-buffer-names))
```